# Different approach to try-except blocks

Tags: python, try-except

```html
try:
    pos = name.find("#")
    name = name[:pos]
except:
    pass
try:
    pos = name.find("TDCJ")
    name = name[:pos]
except:
    pass
```

Is there a way to combine these two try and except? My program keeps on building I feel like there is way too many try and excpet blocks. How do I avoid adding try and except often?

Comment: Depending on your actual code, this might be a case of [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), so maybe think about putting that into a function. Also keep in mind, that the except should actually have action to handle the problem. I guess/hope the `pass` there is just for a more concise question here.

Answer (score 1):

If the `try-except` is the same you can just loop the desired string elements. Something like the following:

```
l = ["#", "TDCJ"]

for elem in l:
    try:
        pos = name.find(elem)
        name = name[:pos]
    except:
        pass
```

Generally, you should keep the *Dont Repeat Yourself* (DRY) principle